# How to get magic color enhance in flutter like camscanner

Tags: flutter

I am creating a application same as camscanner with flutter, but i am not able to enhance the image same like in camscanner in my flutter application.

This is the original picture of the image before applying the magic filter in camscanner.

[Before enhancing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVAt5.jpg)

This is the enhanced picture of the same image after applying the magic filter in camscanner

[Image after enhancing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4LAF.jpg)

How to achieve that in the flutter to create filter same like in camscanner

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with flutter development but can surely try to help you with processing images. I guess, you must also be trying to use **OpenCV** for image processing and so you may find this post helpful.

I have used **Adobe Photoshop** to figure out editing techniques required to achieve the scan effect and then implemented those operations using OpenCV.

In Photoshop, the Scanning effect can be achieved using the operations, **"set white point"** & **"set black point"** provided by "Levels" feature. Combination of these two operations result in the scan effect often regarded as **"magic color"** in various mobile apps.

Apart from this, **High Pass Filter** can be used along with above two operations to achieve some exciting results like shadow removal.

Scanning of documents in the "Black & White" mode can be achieved by processing the image in **LAB color space** using OpenCV.

Above mentioned operations can be implemented in OpenCV using various threshold techniques and few basic mathematical operations.

You can once go through [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/sourabhkhemka/DocumentScanner) to get complete insight of what I am trying to say.

I have added a **complete wiki documentation** for the project in above repo.

This answer might not seem to be very informative but since the repo's wiki gives an elaborate discussion, I am keeping this post short.

**Example of results we can achieve using these techniques:**
[image: image 1]

**Markings in this image helps us to understand the type of output from each mode discussed in the GitHub repo:**
[image: image 2]